# Confused about sending variable to partial and showing partial in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

This is taking me ages. I'm sure I have an incorrect understanding of partials but I've done plenty of reading and don't seem to be getting anywhere.

These are the steps I am trying to create.

a) A user clicks on a graph rendered in javascript (`d3.js` library) (on `http://blabla/graph/data`
b) Ajax is triggered and returns the name of the thing that is clicked (in `graph.js`)

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .on("click", function (d) {
        getprofile(d);
    });

function getprofile(d) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/graph/show",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            name: d.name
        },
        success: function (result) {

            console.log(result);
            $('.profile-content').html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

c) The name is passed to the show action of the `graph_controller.rb` to perform a database lookup

```
def show
   @user = User.find_by name: params[:name]
       render :partial=>'profile', :user => @user
end
```

The database lookup works fine and the console tells me that user is returned. Great.

d) Now I want to show the result of the database lookup in the same page that the user clicked in the first page, in a partial `views/graph/_profile.html.erb`. This is where I get confused about how the @user variable gets passed to the partial.

What I have in the partial is:

```
<div>Profile details</div>
<div class='profile-content'></div>
<div>User</div>
<%= @user.name %>
```

but I get the error `NoMethodError in Graph#data` with a highlight of the line

```
<%= @user.name %>  `undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass`
```

in the partial. This is triggered before the page loads it seems

However, if the partial contains `<%= @user %>` instead of `<%= @user.name %>` then I can see no errors in the console and it returns an object with all the correct fields for the user. The partial is rendered on the page, but there is nothing where the <%= @user %> should be

Basically how do I get the partial to update and show me the object? Constructive would be nice instead of 'read a textbook'. If you don't like the question please just don't answer.

Comment: It sounds like what is happening is that there isn't a user with that name, and so @user is nil.  In this case, `<%= @user %>` wouldn't cause any errors, as it's just like saying `<%= nil %>` which will render an empty string.  However, calling .name on nil will give you the error you're seeing.  The only bit i don't understand is "it returns an object with all the correct fields for the user".  What do you mean?  Where are you seeing this?

Comment: render :partial=>'profile', :user => @user  goes in the view not the controller

Comment: I had another look at the console and I guess you're right. It says Processing by GraphController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"name"=>"Feuilly"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."name" = 'Feuilly' LIMIT 1
  Rendered graph/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms) but it doesn't show me the object is returned. I'm not sure why that would be

Comment: Ignore previous comments. This time I know it has achieved a proper database lookup as using byebug the display at_user shows 1: at_user = #<User id: 68, name: "MotherPlutarch", group: 9, email: nil> which is only achievable by performing the query based on what the user has clicked. Therefore the question is how do I get @user into the partial?

Comment: if youre passing it the local `user`, you dont need `@user` in the partial, but should just be able to use `user`

Comment: When I replace @user with user in the partial I get the error NameError in Graph#data and it highlights <%= user %>

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, you don't need to render the partial, render the view instead:

```
def show
   @user = User.find_by name: params[:name]
   render 'profile'
end
```

rename your partial from views/graph/_profile.html.erb
to: 'views/graph/profile.html.erb'

If you insist on using the partial in views/users/show.html.erb

```
<%= render 'profile', user: @user %>
```

This will search out the file app/views/_profile.html.erb

Comment: Thanks @ilan although I get the error NoMethodError in Graph#data with the partial method you have specified